# How can I customize (add links) to the top menu bar in outlook online

Tags: office365, outlook-web-app

I want to make it easier for user and add custom links to the top menu on Outlook in Office 365. I know I can add them to the app launcher but easier if on the menu. Add links to the right of the word "Outlook"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You cannot customize top menu of Outlook for web.